# Syntax error with Electron and React: unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am developing an application with Electron and want to start using React. 
Because of this, I have installed the react and react-dom packages with:

```
npm install --save react react-dom
```

My javascript file is included with:

```
<script src="js/character-rolling.js"></script>
```

I have added this to the first part of the javascript file:

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");

var Greeting = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
}
});
```

However, when I run the code, chromium developer tools shows the error:

```
character-rolling.js:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

At first sight one would say that the browser cannot interpret the syntax but isn't this supposed to be pure ES5 syntax? I would like to keep my application simple and not start using a tool like Babel. I would think that the browser should interpret this without problems. The electron version:

```
[marco@marco-archLinux deeMemory]$ npm run electron --version
4.0.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it is ES5 syntax but what you are writing is **JSX and not pure Javascript** and hence you get the error `unexpected token <` at `return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;` . You need a tool to convert your `JSX to JS` for your browser to understand.

For this you definitely need `babel`. In order to use it you can use `webpack` which will make use of `babel` to bundle code into a JS file.

Comment: Thank you, I was just wondering if there was a way to avoid setting up webpack and babel but apparently not. I will do that.

Comment: @Perennialista You can [use React without JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html). You can also [use hyperscript helpers for React](https://github.com/jador/react-hyperscript-helpers) if you'd like to make things a bit nicer without introducing build/compile tools.